# having problems running unit tests in xcode after updating cocapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

Well, I updated cocoapods, added a new unit test pod that I wanted to try out, and I am unable to run even the most simple unit test.

It doesn't seem to be an issue with the pod but probably after I updated cocoapods to the newest version then did pod update.

Here's the error I get, basically the error is when I try and pull in any class from my main target into my tests.

[image]

a full size version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5EQP.png

uncomment the lines that are commented out and I get the error, otherwise cmd+U will run and succeed.

```
#import "AppDelegateTests.h"
//#define EXP_SHORTHAND
//#import "Expecta.h"
//#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegateTests {

   // AppDelegate *_appDelegate;
}

- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];
   // _appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
}

- (void)test_rootViewController_should_be_SplitViewController {


   // expect(1).to.equal(1);
}

- (void)tearDown
{
    // Tear-down code here.

    [super tearDown];
}

@end
```

Comment: Whenever I get weird errors like this I: a) Clean the project, and if that doesn't work, b) delete anything built under the DerivedData folder.

Comment: Also check that your app target is still in the target dependencies for your test target. And are you running a DP version of Xcode?